# How could I locate the xpath for below sequence

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

How could i locate the xpath for the below sequence of dynamic changing id's

The sequence is like this

```
//*[@id="fli_list_item_5c7c4499-c9d1-45b7-b1df-d51c2f849140"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 1
//*[@id="fli_list_item_5c7c4499-c9d1-45b7-b1df-d51c2f849140"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 2    

//*[@id="fli_list_item_89b1488a-4b9a-4ed4-a8db-1040c88bae82"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 3
//*[@id="fli_list_item_89b1488a-4b9a-4ed4-a8db-1040c88bae82"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 4

//*[@id="fli_list_item_cdebfe1d-0f94-4a4b-a1f0-8024bb816464"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 5 
//*[@id="fli_list_item_cdebfe1d-0f94-4a4b-a1f0-8024bb816464"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button       -- button 6
```

so, using

//*[contains(@id, "fli_list_item_")]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button

gives me 3 buttons to select.

Below is the full HTML for the div which includes button

```html
<div class="make_flex spaceBetween"><div class="faresLeftSection"><ul class="faresListing"><li class="make_flex"><span class="viewFaresIcon" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://imgak.mmtcdn.com/flights/assets/media/dt/common/multifare/tick-green.png?v=5&quot;);"></span><span class="flexOne"><span class="service-text">Cabin Baggage 7 Kgs, Check-in Baggage 15 Kgs</span></span></li><li class="make_flex"><span class="viewFaresIcon" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://imgak.mmtcdn.com/flights/assets/media/dt/common/multifare/tick-green.png?v=5&quot;);"></span><span class="flexOne"><span class="service-text">Free seats available</span></span></li><li class="make_flex"><span class="viewFaresIcon" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://imgak.mmtcdn.com/flights/assets/media/dt/common/multifare/tick-green.png?v=5&quot;);"></span><span class="flexOne"><span class="service-text">Partially-refundable fare</span></span></li><li class="make_flex"><span class="viewFaresIcon" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://imgak.mmtcdn.com/flights/assets/media/dt/common/multifare/tick-green.png?v=5&quot;);"></span><span class="flexOne"><span class="service-text">Date change chargeable</span></span></li></ul></div><div class="faresRightSection"><div class="pull-left  make_relative price"><p><span class="actual-price">₹ 3,075</span></p></div><button class="btn fli_primary_btn text-uppercase"> Book Now </button></div></div>
```

Comment: Post your relevant HTML of button?

Comment: updated the question and posted the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on `Book Now` button induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `elementToBeClickable`() and following **xpath**.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Book Now')]"))).click();
```

OR

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='faresRightSection']//button[contains(.,'Book Now')]"))).click();
```

**EDIT**: Use index if you are still getting multiple elements.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@class='faresRightSection']//button[contains(.,'Book Now')])[1]"))).click();
```

Comment: Tried both the xpath you have given but it still gives me multiple results for Book Now. It is not giving me a single locator element which I am trying to click.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: @vishalgupta : Try with index if you are still getting multiple elements.Check Edit sections.Index 1 is the first element.

Comment: https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=BOM-TIR-28/06/2020&tripType=O&paxType=A-1_C-0_I-0&intl=false&cabinClass=E

Comment: using index worked in this case. The elements are very dynamic in this URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contains in xpath. More examples [here](https://devhints.io/xpath).

```
//*[contains(@id, "fli_list_item_")]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button
```

Comment: using the above statement gives me 3 buttons to select. I have updated the question and posted the full HTML